# Finding the longest element $w_0$ of the reflection group $S_n$ with respect to the positive system $\{e_i - e_j, 1≤i < j≤1\}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, reflection, coxeter-groups

### Preliminaries

Let $V = \mathbb R^n$, and $W = S_n$ the symmetric group. We consider the set $\Phi = \{±(e_i - e_j) \mid 1 ≤ i < j ≤ n\} $ (where the $e_i$ are the standard vectors), which is a [root system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system#Definition) in $V$. We let $S_n$ act on $\mathbb R^n$ by permuting the standard vectors $e_1, \dots, e_n$ (permuting the subscripts). We have that $\langle W(\Phi) \rangle := \{s_\alpha: \alpha \in \Phi \} = S_n $ (where $s_\alpha$ is the reflection that sends $\alpha$ to $-\alpha$ and fixes the hyperplane orthogonal to $\alpha$); in other words, the reflections of $\Phi$ generate $S_n$. (The $s_{\alpha}$ for $\alpha = e_i - e_j$ are exactly the transpositions, and it's commonly known that $S_n$ is generated by transpositions.) In this context, $\Phi$ is generally considered the standard root system for $S_n$.

Let $\Delta$ be a [simple system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system#Positive_roots_and_simple_roots) of $\Phi$, and $\Pi$ the respective [positive system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system#Positive_roots_and_simple_roots) for $\Delta$. I already know that each $w \in W$ can be written as a product of positive/simple reflections. For $w \in W$, we call $l(w)$ the *length* of $W$ if $l(w) = r \in \mathbb N$ and $r$ is the minimal number so that there exists $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_r \in \Delta $ with $w = s_{\alpha_1} \dots s_{\alpha_r}$.

It can be shown that the length of a $w$ is exactly the number of positive roots (for some fixed $\Delta$ and $\Pi$) that are sent to negative roots  by $w$; in other words, $l(w) = |\Pi \cap w^{-1}(-\Pi)|$. There are some more interesting properties of the length function, like $l(w w') \equiv l(w) + l(w') \mod 2$ or $l(w s_\alpha) = l(w) ± 1$, but in general, the length behaves "as one would expect".

We call a $w_0 \in W$ the longest element if $l(w_0)$ is maximal; that is, if $l(w) ≤ l(w_0) \quad \forall w ≠ w_0$. It can be shown that the longest element is unique (so we have $l(w) < l(w_0) \forall w ≠ w_0$), and that for any $w \in W$, we can get to $w_0$ by multiplying $w$ with all $s_\alpha$ for which the length increases. Especially, we have $l(w_0) = |\Pi|$ (because $w_0$ must send all positive roots to negative ones, which was one of the characterizations of the length function).

### My question

I want to find the longest element $w_0$ of $S_n$ for the root system $\Phi = \{±(e_i - e_j) \mid 1 ≤ i < j ≤ n\}$ and the positive system $\Pi = \{(e_i - e_j) \mid 1 ≤ i < j ≤ n\}$ (by letting $S_n$ act on $e_1, \dots, e_n$ by permuting the coordinates, as described above).

Now I've already stated above what this $w_0$ must satisfy: it must be an element of $S_n$, that, acting on $\Phi$ in the way described above, has maximal length $|\Pi|$. I also know that all the $e_i - e_j$ must be sent to $e_j - e_i$ because $w_0$ sends all positive roots to negative ones. I'm not really sure how to go from there though; I'm still lacking the intuition on how to get from the roots back to the elements of $S_n$.

I've also already stated above that $w_0$ can be gotten by suczessively multiplying the $s_\alpha, \alpha \in \Delta$ together for all the $\alpha$ for which the length increases, but my problem here is that I'm not entirely sure what the respective simple system $\Delta$ for the given positive system $\Phi$ looks like.

I might be missing something obvious here, but I've been sitting on this question for a while now and I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The longest element for each type, in particular for type $\mathsf{A}_n$, is described in the tables at the end of Bourbaki's "Lie groups and Lie algebras", Chapters 4-6. - It is decribed through its action on the simple roots, or which is the same, through its action on the nodes of the Dynkin diagram. In this way, $w_o$ corresponds to a diagram automorphism.

For type $\mathsf{A}_n$, the element $w_o$ corresponds to the diagram automorphism which swaps the line in the middle. In formulas, we have $w_o(\alpha_i)=-\alpha_{n+1-i}$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$, where $\alpha_i$ is the $i$th simple root, i.e. we have $\alpha_i=\epsilon_i-\epsilon_{i+1}$.

I am not sure what kind of description of $w_o$ you are looking for. But from this, you can figure out the action of $w_o$ on each $\epsilon_i$, and even describe $w_o$ as a permutation.

Comment: "... its action on the simple roots, or which is the same, through its action on the nodes of the Dynkin diagram. In this way, $w_0$ corresponds to a diagram automorphism. " I think this is misleading, and it's not what Bourbaki does. Rather, diagram automorphisms are made to correspond to elements in $Aut(R) \setminus W(R)$, whereas $w_0 \in W(R)$. In cases $A_{n \ge 2}, D_{2n+1}$ and $E_6$, Bourbaki calls "$\epsilon$" the unique element in $Aut(R) \setminus W(R)$ which "swaps" the roots in the basis acc. to the diagram automorphism, then notes that $w_0 = -\epsilon$. In all other cases ...

Comment: (cont'd) ..., $w_0 = -id$. This includes the cases $D_{2n}$ in particular, where $w_0$ does **not** in any sensible way "correspond" to the "swapping" automorphism. Finally, in case $A_{n \ge 2}$, I think it is more enlightening to realise that $w_0$ is not "the element that swaps the roots", but rather the reason why both $-id$ and $\epsilon$ (the actual root-swapper with $\epsilon(\alpha_i) = \alpha_{n+1-i})$ represent the non-trivial element in the quotient $Aut(R)/W(R)$: because $-id = \epsilon \cdot w_0$ (and/or $\epsilon = -id \cdot w_0$).